# Graphhopper: Adding weight to edges using OSM id

Tags: graphhopper

I have a pbf file of the greater Chicago area and have been able to load this file using the graphhopper web viewer.

I would like to improve bike routing using additional usage data that I have for road segments (each identified by an OSM id).

From this SO answer [how-to-quickstart-graphhopper-with-my-own-multimodal-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284260/how-to-quickstart-graphhopper-with-my-own-multimodal-graph/20292446#20292446), I understand that I will need to feed the usage data I have into the GraphHopperStorage.  A few questions about doing so:

1) My usage data references OSM ids.  How do I reference edges in my pbf file to an OSM id?  I also have the lat/lon coordinates of the head/tail of each segment -- from what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27070435/185064), I believe that I will have to use these for my mapping?

2) Once I have created MyGraphHopperStorage, can I persist the addition of the weighting so that I do not have to perform this at every run?

Thanks

tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My usage data references OSM ids. How do I reference edges in my pbf file to an OSM id?

You'll need to keep a (Hash)Map while import for convert between internal and OSM IDs (either edge or node). To keep using osm id even after the import see [this example project](https://github.com/karussell/graphhopper-osm-id-mapping)

> can I persist the addition of the weighting so that I do not have to perform this at every run?

You can store this into the flags and call graph.flush, see my recent [traffic data post](https://graphhopper.com/blog/2015/04/08/visualize-and-handle-traffic-information-with-graphhopper-in-real-time-for-cologne-germany-koln/)

Comment: could you provide the new link of that article ? the link you used in your answer is dead. Thx